# Organic Groups - how to display a summary view of members of the group based on a "company" field added to the user profile

Tags: organic-groups, views

I want to create a block to display on my organic group nodes that shows the number of members of the group summarized by a field in the user profile (company)  for instance:

Company 1 (4)
Company 2 (1)
Company 6 (3)

I have played around with relationships adding a few trying to get the field I need and using the "(OG group) OG group: Og group ID" as a contextual filter--  I can get the field label (Company) to show up in the block view but the values don't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the default OG Members view and cloned it (keep the original) and changed from user: name to my field user:company - added aggregation - in advanced settings in the other section - then had to change the contextual filter to use the GID from the active node. then played around with the aggregation to get it to work ... overall it does what I needed.

Lesson learned ... use the views you get from adding modules - smart people built them ;-)